# Amazon S3 SDK will not be able to connect to HCP via AD users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are in process of integrating HCP (Hitachi Content Platform) Object Store using the Amazon S3 Client.

We can be able to perform all Activities like Add, Delete, List Objects using the Amazon S3 Client along with the User Credentials i.e User: adminXXX, Password: abcXXXX.

Our main requirement is to use our AD Accounts instead of User Accounts. We have mapped AD Accounts over the HCP Buckets and after exploring forums we got to know Amazon S3 SDK will not be able to connect to HCP via AD users.

Is there any turnaround solution for this issue, we are trying to achieve this  by using the .net Console App.

Comment: Can you supply the forum link or so, where you were to figure out the SDK cannot reach to HCP with AD user entries?

Comment: @vahdet: i have checked with HCP team members and they have shared this info for this limitation issue with Amazon S3 SDK